# Can I check Ngnix running status and return 1 or 0 based on the state?

Tags: linux, bash, nginx, scripting

I have a command which checks whether a port is open and returns zero or one.

```
netstat -ano | grep ':443\s' | if grep -q LISTEN; then echo 0; else echo 1; fi
```

I would like to know how can we write a command to check whether nginx is running and return 1 or 0?

Comment: `pgrep nginx >/dev/null; echo $?` ? Also, you code returns 0, and prints 0 or 1 depending on the port.

Comment: `foo () { netstat -ano | grep '443\s' | grep -q LISTEN; }`. The exit status of `foo` is 0 if it finds "LISTEN" on the port, 1 otherwise.

Comment: @KamilCuk thanks you made it so simple, this what I'm expecting

Answer (score 2):

```
pidof nginx && echo 1 || echo 0
```

Comment: How can I hide PID's in the output?

`pidof nginx && echo 0 || echo 1`

**Output**
12258 12256
0

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pidof tool which comes with system package (for instance procps-ng under RedHat GNU/Linux distributions), redirect the output you do not want, and manage to gave the status you want.

For sustainability, I wrote you this tiny script you can integrate in yours:

```
#!/bin/bash

function isRunning() {
  local _processName="$1"
  pidof "$_processName" >/dev/null
}

isRunning nginx && echo "It is running" || echo "Not running"
```

If you really want to echo a 1 or 0, you can, but it would generally be useless.

Instead you can act according to the return of this function isRunning.

Edit according to your comment: you can use this for any process:

```
#!/bin/bash

function isRunning() {
  local _processName="$1"
  echo -ne "Checking if $_processName is running ... " 
  pidof "$_processName" >/dev/null && echo "1" || echo "0"
}

isRunning nginx
isRunning java
isRunning httpd
```

You can remove the echo in the function if you do not want anything else than 0/1.

Comment: I want 1 or 0 because I'm monitoring it through AWS cloudwatch, If nginx is stopped we are planning to raise an alarm, by the way, Can I use this script for even other processes like java or HTTPD?

Comment: Hi, yes you can; it is why I wrote a function you can use. You just need to specify the name of what you want check. I will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks mate this is really very helpful @Bsquare

Comment: When I run the following script manually the values are fine, but when I run it through cronjob the value is coming different any idea?
`#!/bin/bash
NGINXSTATUS=$(pidof "$nginx" >/dev/null && echo "0" || echo "1")
echo $NGINXSTATUS >> a.txt`

Comment: Yes. What is the user you use in crontab and in console? Anyway You must remove the $ before nginx.

Comment: I'm using ec2-user in crontab This is my crontab `* * * * * /bin/sh /home/ec2-user/custommetrics/mon.sh` and tried with ec2-user an root user in console both are giving correct outputs from console, I'm always getting the value "1" when cronjob runs the script

Comment: Did you remove the useless $? Ending with `NGINXSTATUS=$(pidof "nginx"` otherwise, it will launch pidof <empty string> and will always return the pid of all running process, according to your user permissions.  You may temporary try without `>/dev/null` to see what is the return of **pidof**.

Answer (score 0):

With systemd you can use "systemctl status nginx" and then look at the "$?" variable (exit code of the last executed command).

I think something like this will do the job:

```
systemctl status nginx >/dev/null 2>&1; if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then echo 0; else echo 1; fi
```

Answer (score -1):

The best way is actually use systemd since Nginx runs as a service. you can even interpret the status of **running** function later on according to systemd exit codes.

```
function running() { 
   [[ ! -z $1 ]] &&   systemctl status $1 2>&1 >/dev/null  || return 255; 
   return $?; 
}

running nginx && echo "Its running" || echo "Its not"
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more whats happening in this line?
`[[ ! -z $1 ]] &&   systemctl status $1 2>&1 >/dev/null  || return 255; `

Comment: yes, basically it checks that you actually passed a parameter to the function you are declaring by checking whether the **$1** is empty. If it is, then it returns 255, 
 otherwise, it runs the **systemctl status YOURSERVICE** statemnt, and then on the next line it returns the $? variable which is then checked in the example I gave and if its 0 it prints "Its running". For any non zero exit status it prints "its not". You could  fine tune this and actually check what each exit code of systemctl means, so you can know exactly why its not running.